Resistor purpose in following circuit

I would like to understand Why is there a small 20 ohm resistor next to the transformer? What is its purpose?

לירן גלמידי - Hi, It seems the image isn't yours, so where did it come from? To comply with the site referencing rule, details of the original source of copied / adapted material must be provided by you, next to each copied / adapted item. If the original source is online & public, please [edit] the question & add the webpage/PDF name & its link (URL) (e.g. website name + webpage title + its URL). If the source is offline (e.g. printed book / private intranet) then see the site rule for advice. || See the [tour] & [help] for the site rules as they differ from forums.

The 20 ohm resistor is inserted into the feedback path to "break" the loop.  The value is small enough to not affect the feedback divider, but large enough to allow an isolated (via transformer) small excitation signal to be imposed across it.
This allows you to keep the loop closed, while "perturbing" the loop with an AC signal.  You can sweep that signal and measure the ratio of channel B to channel A, which will then be the frequency response around the whole loop.
Tektronix has a good explanation here.

I don't think there's a lot of context here with the power stage device but it sort of looks like a sense resistor, typically used to measure the voltage drop across it, or effectively, the current draw from whatever device your Channel A and Channel B inputs are.
